# ImageIO.read(...) - It is very slow, is there a better way?

Tags: java

I am loading tons of icons that are going to be used in my application. I plan to load all of them from the jar on server startup. However, with hundreds of images adding up to just over 9MB, it is still taking over 30 seconds to perform this task. I am doing it in a separate thread right now but it is making me wonder if I am doing something inefficiently in my code. I borrowed code from SO to load the information into my structures. I put the code into a test class and profiled it. 99% of the profile is on the ImageIO.read(..) method. So that is definitely the bottleneck. Below is that test class that should provide a picture as to how I am using ImageIO.

```
public class IconTest {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.net.URISyntaxException
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    URI uri = IconTest.class.getResource("Icons").toURI();
    Path myPath;
    if (uri.getScheme().equals("jar")) {
        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap());
        myPath = fileSystem.getPath("Icons/");
    } else {
        myPath = Paths.get(uri);
    }
    IconFolder root = new IconFolder(myPath.toFile().getName());
    IconFolder parentFolder = root;
    HIcon currentIcon = null;
    IconFolder folder = null;
    HashMap<String,IconFolder> folders = new HashMap<>();
    folders.put(parentFolder.getName(), parentFolder);
    Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(myPath, 5);
    Iterator<Path> it = walk.iterator();it.next();
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Path path = it.next();
        if(path.toFile().isDirectory()){
            folder = new IconFolder(path.toFile().getName());
            folders.put(folder.getName(), folder);
            String parentName = path.getParent().toFile().getName();
            parentFolder = folders.get(parentName);
            parentFolder.addSubFolder(folder);
            currentIcon =null;
            System.out.println("Directory: " + path);
        }else{
            URL url = path.toUri().toURL();

            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(url));
            //Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url);
            //ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(image);
            String[] iconName;
            iconName = path.getFileName().toString().replaceAll("_000000", "").replaceAll(".png","").split("_",2);
            String imageName = iconName[0];
            String imageSize = iconName[1];
            if(currentIcon==null||!currentIcon.getName().equals(imageName)){
                currentIcon = new HIcon(imageName);
                folder.addIcon(currentIcon);
                currentIcon.setIcon(icon, imageSize );
            }else{
                currentIcon.setIcon(icon, imageSize);
            }
            //System.out.println("Image: " + imageName+"-->"+imageSize);
        }
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
}
```

Any pointers would be helpful. I looked at a number of the SO posts that I think are pointing out the same thing. I am using a MacBook Air with SSD so I would think this would be lightning fast.

I added a screenshot of the profile results below:

[image: Java profile in netbeans]

This is a profile after setting `setUseCache` to false:

[image: Java profile after setUseCache = false]

Comment: I would question the entire strategy. I would load them as you need them. Distribute the pain.

Comment: It will probably be substantially faster to put your icons in one image and chop them up later. 100s of images read from the bowels of a jar is likely to be inefficient.

Comment: @pvg - see my comment on the below answer. What about putting them in zip file, loading the 1 file into memory then do my walking and read in memory?

Comment: Aren't they in a jar? That's already a zip file. Storing them in some binary blob that you just read into memory would probably also work. Main reason I mention the chopping is it's (or was?) a pretty common web technique and there are tools that can help. It will also give you some space saving and likely better compression.

Comment: Yeah it's in a jar. I was thinking the zipping it up I can then load the zip file as a binary blob then create an ZipInputStream from the blob instead of from inside the jar. I thought it may be much faster to have it all in memory.

Comment: The zip seems like overkill. You can just write the concatenated files as a blob of bytes and then make a stream out of that, read images from it sequentially. Either way, I don't think it's a memory thing, if you run this a couple of times even the way it's now, all you're doing is moving data around memory. It's just that there's processing overhead in accessing files, especially pretend-files in a pretend-filesystem. Making a blob or zip or whatever ensures you get sequential layout and a few operations to read the thing in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found a solution somewhat. Below is the latest profile:

[image]

This is a really interesting solution. I decided to use an executor so that the read operation could be parallelized. I was already creating a thread for running the whole task but break this up into even more granular tasks really made this fast.

In the end I was able to get this down to 3.4 seconds from 38.9 seconds. That is a big gain in my book. This is important to me because I want my server to startup as fast as possible and I definitely did not want to lose 39 seconds of startup time.

I chose to hardcode it to 5 threads because I am developing on my mac and it only has 4 cores. I tried up to 15 and above cores+1 it loses efficiency.

Below is the adjusted sample code:

```
public class IconTest {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.net.URISyntaxException
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, IOException {
    test4();
}

public static void test4() throws MalformedURLException, IOException, URISyntaxException{
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    URI uri = IconTest.class.getResource("../resources/Icons").toURI();
    Path myPath;
    if (uri.getScheme().equals("jar")) {
        FileSystem fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap());
        myPath = fileSystem.getPath("Icons/");
    } else {
        myPath = Paths.get(uri);
    }
    IconFolder root = new IconFolder(myPath.toFile().getName());
    IconFolder parentFolder = root;
    HIcon currentIcon = null;
    IconFolder folder = null;
    HashMap<String,IconFolder> folders = new HashMap<>();
    folders.put(parentFolder.getName(), parentFolder);
    Stream<Path> walk = Files.walk(myPath, 10);
    Iterator<Path> it = walk.iterator();it.next();
    Info.Info("Starting loading icons....");
    ImageIO.setUseCache(false);
    while(it.hasNext()){
        Path path = it.next();
        if(path.toFile().isDirectory()){
            folder = new IconFolder(path.toFile().getName());
            folders.put(folder.getName(), folder);
            String parentName = path.getParent().toFile().getName();
            parentFolder = folders.get(parentName);
            parentFolder.addSubFolder(folder);
            currentIcon =null;
            Info.Info("Directory: " + path);
        }else{
            ImageLoadingTask task;
            URL url = path.toUri().toURL();
            String[] iconName;
            iconName = path.getFileName().toString().replaceAll("_000000", "").replaceAll(".png","").split("_",2);
            String imageName = iconName[0];
            String imageSize = iconName[1];
            if(currentIcon==null||!currentIcon.getName().equals(imageName)){
                currentIcon = new HIcon(imageName);
                folder.addIcon(currentIcon);
                task = new ImageLoadingTask(url,currentIcon,imageSize);
                service.submit(task);
            }else{
                task = new ImageLoadingTask(url,currentIcon,imageSize);
                service.submit(task);
            }
            //Info.Info("Image: " + imageName+"-->"+imageSize);
        }
    }
    service.shutdown();
    Info.Info("Finished loading icons....");
}

static public class ImageLoadingTask implements Callable<ImageIcon> {

    private final URL url;
    private final HIcon hIcon;
    private final String size;

    public ImageLoadingTask(URL url, HIcon hIcon, String size ) {
        this.url = url;
        this.hIcon=hIcon;
        this.size=size;
    }

    @Override
    public ImageIcon call() throws Exception {
        ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(url));
        hIcon.setIcon(icon, size);
        return icon;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Nice solution, try using `Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()` instead of 5 so your app will automatically chose the number of threads based on how many native threads the machine has.

Comment: Thanks!! Yeah I use that elsewhere, I wrote that note because I realized when I was writing the answer that I forget to change that from being hardcoded...#Lazy  lol. I chose to point it out rather than modify it...hahaha

Comment: If you want to share your images folder, I can maybe look into speeding it up further through memory mapped files.

Comment: I am cool with 3 seconds actually. how much faster do you think it could get? Now I am a bit interested. They are just image8 icons of size 25,50,100 for each...the color package.

Comment: setIcon, being a Swing method, should be called from the EDT. The actual image read can still be done in the background, though. You could probably just slap the setIcon into an invokeLater.

Comment: Actually, that is my own class, it is not a swing method. I have it as a container that holds 3 different ImageIcons of different sizes. Probably poor choice for a method name on my part, can cause confusion.

Comment: That is a very odd outcome indeed given that even the most embarrassingly parallelizable tasks tend to scale linearly or worse. Yours somehow scales better than that! One possibility is that something is becoming hot and JIT'ed earlier in the multithreaded case so you get the benefit sooner.

Comment: I don't know about that. It seems right to me. average of 3 seconds per pool and there are 5 pool threads that amounts to 15 seconds of work. The previous profile shows 15.2 seconds of total work on the read method. Now I am losing time on overhead so it's actually more like 20+seconds of work completed now outside of just the pool threads .

Comment: Maybe it seems right to you because you're looking at different timings. What I read in your post is you went from 40 seconds to 3.4 seconds. That is, you added 5 threads and it got 10 times faster. That normally doesn't happen.

Comment: Ohhhh gotchya. The first thing I did ( noted with second profile in question ) was disabled the cache which brought it down to about 21 seconds. so the 5 threads brought it from 21 seconds to 3.4 seconds. Of that 21 seconds was the 15.2 for the readbytes method I referenced above.

Answer (score 4):

You can try to use `ImageIO.setUseCache(false)` in order to use memory-based caching instead of disk-based caching (since it is the default one).

Reference: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#setUseCache(boolean)

Comment: I actually did this...and it did drop the time significantly but I am still over 20 seconds. I have a new profile I will post.

Comment: I just updated my post with another suggestion for improving the 16 seconds spent in `getImageReaders` method.

Comment: oops... please ignore my suggestion, I just saw your second screenshot, I'm not sure it is relevant anymore....

Comment: Yeah...and `ImageIO` is actually a final class and the methods are static too. I was thinking about adding them as a zipped file to the jar and then loading the big file once and making a ZipFileSystem, walk it in memory and read from memory...what do you think?

Comment: Yeah... Shame on me, I forgot to check the basics... Your idea looks good: you load everything in memory (minimizing the I/O) and then unzip and read files from there... It's worth trying... unless you RAM sucks ;)

Answer (score 2):

`ImageIO#read` is a utility method which does a bunch of stuff under the covers.

If you know, for instance, that all your images are in the same format, you could use `ImageIO#getImageReadersByFormatName` to get the readers once (apparently this is 3/4 of your startup time), get the reader you want to use (often just the first one), and then use that reader for all your images without having to search again.

Comment: If you look at the second profile, I fully expand it out. The time is in the readBytes method.

Comment: Ah. Well... I know how I would personally speed that up - group all icons into a single image and cut it up after it's read - but it isn't a solution I'd necessarily recommend for all cases. :)