# ImageIO.read() takes about 13000ms on 5.XMB Image File. How can I improve this performance?

Tags: java, java-8, bufferedimage, image-resizing, javax.imageio

I want to read a `File` to a `BufferedImage` as I want to resize my image. For the resize operation, I have to get a `BufferedImage`.

So, I used `ImageIO.read(file)`, but it takes over 10000ms when file's size is over 5MB. This is my code:

```
...

public BufferedImage change(File file) {
    return ImageIO.read(file);
}

...
```

I don't understand why it takes so much time. And I want to know how to improve it's performance...

Comment: These posts may be related to your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44170127/imageio-read-it-is-very-slow-is-there-a-better-way/44170254 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40468494/why-imageio-read-sooo-slow

Comment: these solutions were not help for me... @JuniorDussouillez

Comment: You could try loading into memory first. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62852645/efficient-way-to-read-an-image-file-using-java/62862626#62862626

Comment: Can you share the image (file) that causes this performance? Disabling disk caching may help a bit, but probably the problem is the way the image is encoded.

Comment: https://unsplash.com/photos/a-QH9MAAVNI 
Here is link where i downloaded image to test over 5MB
@HaraldK

Comment: I solved this problem with @DuncG 's solution.
I read a FIle to a ImageIcon. The ImageIcon can be changed to Image.
As far as I concerned, BufferedImage extends Image.
So, I read File to Image.

Comment: ImageIcon uses [`Toolkit.createImage(URL)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html#createImage-java.net.URL-) under the hood. The main difference to ImageIO is that this will load the image asynchronously. You don’t need to hide what’s going on but can use that method directly.

Comment: Thanks @kiesok. I finally found some time to test. On my computer, your image is read in ~5.6s, using standard ImageIO. And ~1.7s using my TwelveMonkeys JPEG ImageIO plugin. Sadly, using `Toolkit.getImage()` and properly converting to `BufferedImage` takes 360ms. Room for improvement...